# adding yes or no confirmation in jquery dialog popup from code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have use jquery dialog  popup for showing message in popup and Ihave passed message from code behind.Now I want yes or no confirmation in popup and if user clicks yes then only proceed to delete. But I dont have any idea that how to perform from code behind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowPopup(message) {
            $(function () {
                $("#dialog").html(message);
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                    buttons: {
                        text: "Yes",
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    text: "No",
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    modal: true
                });
            });
        };

</script>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
</div>
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       string   message = "Are you sure you  want to delete";


       Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);



        DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

        sQLcONN.Open();
        MySqlCommand objcmd = new MySqlCommand("delete   from shoppingcart where with_puja = '" + Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["id"]).ToString() + "'", sQLcONN);
        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Bindgrid();
        sQLcONN.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
    }
    }
```

Comment: when user clicks yes then only delete that otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Set the confirmation value in a hidden field from the js

**ASP CODE:**

```
<asp:HiddenField id="ConfirmBit" runat="server" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
      $("#dialog").hide(); 
      function ShowPopup(message) {
             $("#dialog").html(message);
             $("#dialog").show(); 
             $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                              $('#ConfirmBit').val("YES");
                              $(this).dialog('close');
                           },
                     "No": function () {
                              $('#ConfirmBit').val("NO");
                              $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                },
                modal: true
            });
       }
   });
```

Now Compare the Comparison bit in the code behind and based on that perform the further operation.

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
   string   message = "Are you sure you  want to delete";


   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);

    string cBit= ConfirmBit.Value;
    if(cBit.Equals("YES"))
    {
       DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
       sQLcONN.Open();
       MySqlCommand objcmd = new MySqlCommand("delete   from shoppingcart where with_puja = '" + Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["id"]).ToString() + "'", sQLcONN);
       objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       Bindgrid();
       sQLcONN.Close();
    }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
  }
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: do I need to include <div id="dialog" style="display: none"></div> in aspx page?

Comment: my popup box is not coming :(

Comment: @user3247426: there were few errors i have corrected it now. you can just add this to aspx page `<div id="dialog"></div>`

Comment: but the problem is same.No popup.

Comment: Was it coming up previously ? btw, could you check if there is any error in the console of your browser

Comment: If I dont include yes or no in popup it is coming.

Comment: I dont see any error in the js code,http://jsfiddle.net/KREyj/8/.check ur js code with this copy

Comment: Sorry dreamweicer to trouble you again and again but that page is not opening.

Comment: :sorry for late response.I tried that yes or no popup came but when I click yes delete function should be trigeer which is not happening.

Comment: @user3247426: you mean in the jsfiddle or in your copy  ?